# How do I mark code to be excluded from code coverage analysis in VSTS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest, ncover

NCover has an attribute `IgnoreFromCoverage` that allows for code to be marked for exclusion during code coverage analysis. Is there a way to do this with the VSTS Code Coverage Tools?

Obvious uses for this would be auto property getters and setters, non obvious uses may be code generated by R# equals implementation or ORM generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2010 you can use the `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage` attribute. You can apply the attribute to an entire class or to methods within a class. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd984116.aspx) for more information.